# SPARQL- Retrieving a DBPedia resource by category string

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

How  can I obtain DBpedia resources based on a Wikipedia category?  For example,
all Japan's islands that have been flooded.
A list of possible categories candidates related to "Flood" include:

- Category:Floods_in_Malaysia
- Category:Floods_in_Singapore
- Category:Floods_in_Japan,
- and many others…

I couldn't navigate using SPARQL queries from categories to certain resources.

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to figure out what SPARQL query to write against DBpedia is to find a Wikipedia with some of the information that you want, then examine the DBpedia resource corresponding to it, and then constructing the query based on that.  For instance, there is a Wikipedia article, [1993 Kagoshima Heavy Rain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Kagoshima_Heavy_Rain).  Based on the naming convention, this leads us to the DBpedia resource http://dbpedia.org/resource/1993_Kagoshima_Heavy_Rain.  Browsing this, we can see how the article is related to the category Floods in Japan.  Particularly, we see that the data contains the following triple:

```
dbpedia:1993_Kagoshima_Heavy_Rain dcterms:subject category:Floods_in_Japan
```

This suggests that we try putting the following query into the [DBpedia SPARQL Endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?event dcterms:subject category:Floods_in_Japan .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+%2a+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fevent+dcterms%3Asubject+category%3AFloods_in_Japan+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

There are two results:

```
event
http://dbpedia.org/resource/1953_North_Kyushu_Flood
http://dbpedia.org/resource/1993_Kagoshima_Heavy_Rain
```

To answer your particular question, you'll have to dig a bit more into the data to find the properties and resources that you need, but you'll follow the same general process.